# Query executed in Microsoft SQL Management and SSRS dataset returns different result

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Issue is that query executed in Management studio returns correct result and in SSRS not. For example in Management Studio for column OriginAndDestinationAddress returns this:

```
"1691 W Warren Blvd, Chicago -> 697 N Frances St, South Bend"
```

But in dataset returns this:

```
"W Warren Blvd, Chicago -> 697 N Frances St, 1691 South Bend"
```

So I am using same query in both cases but results are different and I dont have idea what cause this.

This is query(dataset):

```
  SELECT        CAA.Line1 + ', ' + CAA.City + ' -> ' + CAB.Line1 + ', ' + CAB.City AS       OriginAndDestinationAddress, CAA.Line1 + ',' + CAA.City AS OriginAddress, 
                     CAB.Line1 + ',' + CAB.City AS DestinationAddress, CSI.Height * CSI.Weight * CSI.Depth AS Volume, CSI.Quantity, ISNULL(CSI.ItemVolume, 0) AS ItemVolume, 
                     ISNULL(CSI.HeavyItem, 0) AS HeavyItem, ISNULL(CSI.Damaged, 0) AS Damaged, ISNULL(CSI.DisassemblyReq, 0) AS DisassemblyReq, ISNULL(CSI.AssemblyReq, 
                     0) AS AssemblyReq, ISNULL(CSI.PackingReq, 0) AS PackingReq, ISNULL(CSI.UnpackingReq, 0) AS UnpackingReq, ISNULL(CSI.Electrical, 0) AS Electrical, 
                     ISNULL(CSI.Weight, 0) AS Weight, SIL.ItemName, CAA.Line1, CAA.City, CAB.Line1 AS Expr1, CAB.City AS Expr2
   FROM            Quote AS Q INNER JOIN
                     CustomerSurvey AS CS ON CS.CustomerSurveyId = Q.CustomerSurveyId INNER JOIN
                     CustomerSurveyItem AS CSI ON CSI.CustomerSurveyId = CS.CustomerSurveyId INNER JOIN
                     SurveyItem AS SI ON SI.SurveyItemId = CSI.SurveyItemId INNER JOIN
                     SurveyItemLabel AS SIL ON SIL.SurveyItemId = SI.SurveyItemId INNER JOIN
                     CustomerSurveyAddress AS CSAA ON CSAA.CustomerSurveyAddressId = CSI.OriginAddressId INNER JOIN
                     CustomerSurveyAddress AS CSAB ON CSAB.CustomerSurveyAddressId = CSI.DestinationAddressId INNER JOIN
                     CustomerAddress AS CAA ON CAA.CustomerAddressId = CSAA.CustomerAddressId INNER JOIN
                     CustomerAddress AS CAB ON CAB.CustomerAddressId = CSAB.CustomerAddressId inner join SurveyItemRoom as SIR on SI.SurveyItemId = SIR.SurveyItemId
         WHERE        (Q.QuoteId = @quoteId) AND (SIL.LangId = @CultureId)
         GROUP BY CAA.Line1, CAA.City, CAB.Line1, CAB.City, CSI.Height * CSI.Weight * CSI.Depth, CSI.Quantity, CSI.ItemVolume, CSI.HeavyItem, CSI.Damaged, CSI.DisassemblyReq, 
                     CSI.AssemblyReq, CSI.PackingReq, CSI.UnpackingReq, CSI.Weight,CSI.CustomerSurveyItemId, SIL.ItemName, CAA.Line1, CAA.City, CAB.Line1, CAB.City, CSI.Electrical
```

Comment: Can you show us both queries and the source data please?

Comment: Check the Initial Catalog in your SSRS data source to make sure you're using the same database. Make sure you aren't using a calculated field in your dataset. Copy the query again to make sure it wasn't changed on either end. See if any of this helps.

Comment: I solved this issue.Problem was not in query or dataset. Dataset was correct but rendering data from dataset into tablix origin textbox in tablix was wrong. So I creted textbox outside of tablix and result was correct for it. After that I deleted origin taxtbox in tablix and pasted working outside textbox instead old one. After that everything is working fine.